# How do I evaluate this integral? I tried partial fractions; my answer involved $\ln$, and I don't know if I'm right

Tags: calculus

$$\int \left(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\right)\,dx$$

I tried partial fraction and my answer was all "ln" I dont know if I'm right

My answer looks like this
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right) + C$$

Comment: It could be written $\int \left(1+\frac{2}{x^2-1}\right)dx$.

Comment: When the powers match in the numerator and denominator, it is helpful to reduce the power of the numerator in some fashion. As many have suggested, you can replace $x^2+1$ with $(x^2 - 1) + 2$ and split the fraction that way. Another method, when the substitution is not obvious, is to perform polynomial long division.

Comment: $$\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)\right)'=\frac{1}{x^2-1}$$

Comment: Note that you can always check your own work on indefinite integrals: simply take the derivative of your answer. So in principle, you should never need to say "I don't know if I'm right".

Comment: Easiest way is just to realize this is $1 + \frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\int\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}dx \equiv \underbrace{\int \frac{x^2+1}{(x+1)(x-1)} dx \equiv  \int \left[1+\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1} \right]dx}_{\text{partial fractions: try it yourself!}}=??$$

Answer (score 1):

Your integral can be written as follows:

$$I = \int \frac{x^2 + 1 - 1 + 1}{x^2 - 1} \, \mathrm{d} x,$$ which is equivalent to:

$$I = \int \left(1 + \frac{2}{x^2 - 1} \right)\, \mathrm{d} x = \int \left(1 + \frac{A}{x -  1} + \frac{B}{x+1} \right)\, \mathrm{d} x.$$

Can you solve for $A$ and $B$?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

$\int \left(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\right)\,dx=\int( 1+\frac2{x^2-1})dx=x+\ln\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right) + C$

Answer (score 0):

You're really close. But before you can apply partial fractions the numerator has to have degree less than the denominator, which is not the case here. In order to fix that, you have to do polynomial long division, like so: $$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{rll}
   1\phantom{0000} &&  \\[-3pt]
   x^2-1 \enclose{longdiv}{x^2+1}\kern-.2ex \\[-3pt]
      \underline{x^2-1} &&  \\[-3pt]
      2 &&  \\[-3pt]
  \end{array}
$$
So you get 1 with a remainder of 2, and that gives you $$\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}=1+\frac2{x^2-1}$$
Now you are ready to apply partial fractions, as we have the numerator of degree less than the denominator. Like so: $$\frac2{x^2-1}=\frac A{x-1}+\frac B{x+1}=\frac1{x-1}-\frac1{x+1} $$
where A and B turn out to be 1 and -1, respectively.
We can then plug this back into the integral:
$$\int \frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}dx=\int \left( \frac1{x-1}-\frac1{x+1}+1 \right)dx$$
which becomes $$ln\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)+x+C$$